# PHP get response from server when upload failed

Tags: php, file-upload

I have a PHP script that allows users to upload numerous files. Unfortunately, my web hosting provider (1&1) has set a relatively small maximum file size limit in the `php.ini` file.

Currently, users receive no response when the files submitted exceed the maximum amount allocated to be stored at one time by 1&1. **Is there a way in PHP where I can find out if files are rejected due to this matter and then output a response for that?**

Comment: you can check file size using $_FILE['file']['size'] and throw appropriate error

Comment: FYI, `upload_max_filesize` is a `PHP_INI_PERDIR` directive. You can tweak it to your liking.

Comment: You need to tell the user that the limit is exceeded and they should upload smaller files. You can do this by going through your code, edit and echoing the message correspondingly. If you don't have any coding capability. Look for some one else who is knowledgeable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the value of `$_FILE['file']['error']`. The value is 0 if there were no errors and >0 if there were. Error numbers can be found here: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

You would probably get error 1 (UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE).

Answer (score 2):

File uploading stuff is explained at Features/ [Handling file uploads](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php). If you look at [Error Messages Explained](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php) you'll see you just need to test against `UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE`.

Most modern browsers nowadays support checking file size before uploading (via client-side JavaScript), you should consider adding that check.